# FTPS (FTP-SSL) in Qt 4.6

Tags: qt, ssl, qt4, ftp, openssl

Im trying to get FTP-SSL to work with Qt 4.6.3. I've already compiled Qt with OpenSSL support. Are there any good resources about FTPS with Qt? It seems that QFtp does not provide SSL support. I really dont want to create my own FTPS implementation.

// edit:
I discovered QNetworkAccessManager (ty @ frank) but I cant find any useful documentation or examples for SSL with it. Thats what I'm trying:

```
QUrl url = QUrl("ftp://localhost/filex.txt");
url.setUserName("root");
url.setPassword("root");
QNetworkRequest request(url);
QSslConfiguration SslConfiguration(QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration());
request.setSslConfiguration(SslConfiguration);
manager->get(request);
```

But FileZilla wont let me connect. The FZ console says:

> (000035)21.12.2010 17:31:46 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> USER root
>
> (000035)21.12.2010 17:31:46 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 530 SSL required

FileZilla configuration:

- FTP over SSL/TLS support enabled
- Explicit FTP over TLS enabled
- Plain unencrypted FTP disallowed
- SSL forced for roots login

I would at least expect some sort of `sslErrors` signals since user/pw is fine and SSL fails, but I'm only getting `authenticationRequired` signals.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you checked QNetworkAccessManager?

Comment: @frank thank you very much for your hint frank, see my updated question

Comment: What's your SSL/TLS configuration in FileZilla?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no out of the box solution for FTPS in Qt.

- `QFtp` implements many ftp commands
  but does not support encryption.
- `QNetworkAccessManager` supports only
  basic ftp functions (file
  download/upload) and does not support
  encryption in case of ftp, either. It's
  worth to mention it does support
  encryption for HTTP, which is the
  protocol it's mainly designed for.
- `QSslSocket` implements SSL but no
  specific protocol like FTP or HTTP

Taking above information into consideration an idea comes to mind to mix `QFtp` with `QSslSocket` to get encrypted FTP. The problem is `QFtp` class has no method which would allow to make `QFtp` use user supplied socket. By comparision `QHttp` has such a method - [`int QHttp::setSocket(QTcpSocket * socket)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.5/qhttp.html#setSocket)

Bottom line; according to Thiago Macieira (designer of `QNetworkAccessManager`) the way to go is to implement FTP protocol using `QSslSocket`.

Comment: You better tell thiago to implement this for Qt 4.8 ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer confirms absolutely what i've found out so far. I don't like the idea of reimplementing FTP very much, so we will make QFtp or QNetworkAccessManager SSL-Ready or buy chilkats FTP2 library. Someone should mention that FTPS issue in the Qt manuals - QNetworkAccessManagers FTP- and SSL-support implies FTPS support.